# css align for div tag input boxes

Tags: html, css

I want to display the inputbox with center alignment which is in div tag.Now I did this by using

```
<div class="nam">
  <center><input type="text" name="name"></center>
  <center><input type="text" name="pass"></center>
  <center>
   ... </center>
</div>
```

I want to do this with css code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `<center>` element was deprecated because it defines the presentation of its contents -- it doesn't describe its contents.

There are different ways of [centering the things with CSS](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html).

My suggestions is to adding `text-align: center` to your class `nam`.

```css
.nam {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="nam">
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <input type="text" name="pass">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following

**HTML Code:**

```
<div class="nam">
 <div>
  <input type="text" name="name">
 </div><div>
  <input type="text" name="pass">
 </div>  
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.nam{
    text-align : center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for copying my answer and adding 2 unnecessary `divs` between `input` tags. Have a good day.

Comment: Hey buddy not copying your code.I created in JSFiddle. Check it: http://jsfiddle.net/ketan156/22z6vjrx/3/

Comment: Sure you don't I've `answered 9 mins ago` and you `answered 7 mins ago`. Please :)

Comment: As you think.I find answer myself. But. don't worry you are right ok. :) Within 2 min i copy and edit code and post here right :)